# access class depending on some variable

Tags: php, oop

I have the following problem. I have a class and I inject different classes into it. Depending on some variable I need to load the class:

```
protected $safe;
protected $glass;
public function __construct(
    \My\Path\Block\Dynamicprice\Safe $safe,
    \My\Path\Block\Dynamicprice\Glass $glass
){
    $this->safe = $safe;
    $this->glass = $glass;
}
```

Now I have this hardcoded array:

```
public $_ids=array(
    14534=>'glass',
    7521=>'safe'
);
```

Now down in my code I need to access an class depending on the ID that was given. I tried it like this:

```
$helper =  $this[$this->_ids[$id]];
```

Usually i would write it like:

```
$helper = $this->safe->somePublicMethod();
```

Is it possible to do it dynamically?

But it throws me an error: **Cannot use object of type My\Path\Block\Dynamicprice\Helper as array.**

Is there any way to load this?

Comment: You need this syntax: `$this->{$this->_ids[$id]};`

Comment: What do you mean by "load an class"? Both classes should have been loaded and instantiated when you call the constructor

Comment: @NicoHaase not load, i meant accessing. but its answered already with `$this->{$this->_ids[$id]};`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP allows you to use curly brackets in that case. In your case you are trying to access a class property dynamically. That 's absolutely possible. Have a look at the following example.

```
$helper = $this->{$this->_ids[$id]};
```

If `$id` has the value `7524` this tiny piece of code will give you the `safe` class property.